# Convert NSString to NSDictionary in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring, nsdictionary

This is My string

```
     {
       ColorModel = RGB;
       DPIHeight = 72;
       DPIWidth = 72;
       Depth = 8;
       Orientation = 1;
       PixelHeight = 2848;
       PixelWidth = 4288;
       ProfileName = "Adobe RGB (1998)";
"{Exif}" =     {
       ColorSpace = 1;
       ComponentsConfiguration =         (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        0
    );
    DateTimeDigitized = "2011:03:12 16:17:25";
    DateTimeOriginal = "2011:03:12 16:17:25";
    ExifVersion =         (
        2,
        2
    );
    ExposureBiasValue = 0;
    ExposureProgram = 3;
    ExposureTime = "0.000625";
    FNumber = 4;
    Flash = 0;
    FlashPixVersion =         (
        1,
        0
    );
    FocalLength = 26;
    ISOSpeedRatings =         (
        200
    );
    LightSource = 14;
    MaxApertureValue = 4;
    MeteringMode = 5;
    PixelXDimension = 4288;
    PixelYDimension = 2848;
    SceneCaptureType = 0;
    SensingMethod = 2;
};
"{GPS}" =     {
    Latitude = "38.0374445";
    LatitudeRef = N;
    Longitude = "122.8031783333333";
    LongitudeRef = W;
};
"{IPTC}" =     {
    DateCreated = 20110312;
    DigitalCreationDate = 20110312;
    DigitalCreationTime = 161725;
    ObjectName = "DSC_0001";
    TimeCreated = 161725;
};
"{JFIF}" =     {
    DensityUnit = 1;
    JFIFVersion =         (
        1,
        0,
        1
    );
    XDensity = 72;
    YDensity = 72;
};
"{TIFF}" =     {
    DateTime = "2011:05:03 20:30:44";
    Make = "NIKON CORPORATION";
    Model = "NIKON D90";
    Orientation = 1;
    PhotometricInterpretation = 2;
    ResolutionUnit = 2;
    Software = "QuickTime 7.7.1";
    XResolution = 72;
    YResolution = 72;
};
}
```

I am trying to convert it into NSDictionary by using below code

```
  NSData *myData = [myStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData
                                                             options:kNilOptions
                                                               error:&err];
```

But getting **null** at the end

I thing the problem was string formate...how can i change my string formate to convert it into NSDictionary

EDIT:Getting this error

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No string key for value in object around character 6." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No string key for value in object around character 6.}
```

Any one Please ?

Comment: See that `error` parameter - the one you pass `nil` to? Use that instead of passing `nil` and see what the problem is.

Comment: it looks like your JSON string format is incorrect .

Comment: You have not JSON string. You have dictionary.

Comment: @rmaddy Updated my question can you check once

Comment: @AnupamMishra Ok...how can i change it

Comment: @Keyur  No getting output in the form of string only

Comment: the semicolons (`;`) are not standard separators in JSON; probably that is why your parser fails.

Comment: Keyur is right. This is the `description` of a dictionary... No need to convert anything

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSError *err = nil;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: myData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];
```

Comment: You left out the next lines: `if (!json) NSLog(@"Bad JSON: %@", err);`.

Comment: @rmaddy My intention was just to show json serialization option and using NSError. Anyway thanks for the tip.

Comment: @VishalSonawane Same issue. Bad JSON

Comment: Try to put your string into Online JSON Viewer here :http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/  and check whether it is in correct format.

Comment: @VishalSonawane Getting **Invalid JSON variable**. How can solve this

Comment: Your string is not inproper JSON format. Please go through each dictionary and array contents. Check for open and close braces . Thats what I can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't JSON; it looks more like the output from `[NSDictionary description]`.

In order to get something close to JSON, you need to:

- Change all `=` characters to `:`, to provide `name : value`.
- Change `;` to `,` between elements.
- Change all array delimiters from `( ... )` to `[ ... ]`.
- Add double-quotes around all non-numeric values.

Comment: Droppy above all things are ok..but how to add double-quotes around all non-numeric values.